Search and link to wiki file in vimwiki
I know that one can manually write a link to a file while inside some wiki file.
My question is how could I search for a wiki field that I already have created and then create a link to it in the current place where my cursor is?
I tried searching for it in :h vimwiki but I couldn't find an answer.
